# Implementing Alarm Clock (both iOS and Android) using React Native and Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I am working on an alarm clock using react native with expo. As I understand, I would need to run a background process to listen to scheduled alarms and then trigger them. From what I found, react native doesn't support background process using `setTimeout` but expo does seem to have an `Calendar` and `BackgroundFetch` API which might be useful.

Unfortunately `BackgroundFetch` isn't available in bare expo (non-manage) apps so that's out of question. I pretty much need standard alarm functionality so what are the possible ways it can be done without detaching from expo?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?